# Angular - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of [Added checklist to resolve the issue]

Tags: angular

Angular - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of ..

ERROR in src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:21:26 - error TS2339: Property 'userName' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.

I am getting this error in my component.

login.component.html
<input name="userinfo" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userName">

I did imported the FormModules but still running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Checklist to resolve the issue:

1. Is FormsModule imported in your module (mostly app.module.ts)?
   //import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
2. Is FormsModule included in imports array (mostly app.module.ts)?
   //imports: [ FormsModule ]
3. The Component where you are using the [(ngModel)] is included in declarations array //say LoginComponent
   //declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
4. The Component where you are using the [(ngModel)], is the group of control included inside a  tag?
   //if yes, then you need to add name property to your control
   //ex; <input name="txtName" ...

I spent a lot of time resolving the issue, although it is answered in other question, none of them provide a quick checklist. The anwser(step#4) I was looking like so deep nested on the second page of answer list. So, I have added this checklist to help developers save time, while they can still look out for more detailed answers on the other answered questions.